# What is the difference/relation between FILE * and int value fd?

Tags: c, io

I've noticed that in C language, file I/O relies on a file descriptor. However in some standard library functions like `write(int fd, xxxx)`, the file descriptor seems to be an integer, while in some other functions like `fseek(FILE *stream, xxxx)` it is represented as a pointer.

Are `int` valued fd and `FILE *` the same? Why C language will leave such difference?

(I've tried to find a similar question but failed, though my question seems to be preliminary)

Comment: "Are `int` valued fd and `FILE *` the same?" –  If their type is different, how could they **possibly** be the same? As to "Why C language will leave such difference?": **it doesn't.** The C standard library only uses `FILE` structures. Integer file descriptors are a POSIX artefact and have precisely **nothing** to do with standard C.

Comment: Sorry that my question may be confusing... But I really want to know why some functions need `int fd` but some other need `FILE *stream`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Your comment could interpreted as condescending; perhaps you could mind the wording a bit (sentences like "did you even think about this" does not help anyone).

Comment: `FILE *` is not a file descriptor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard file type in C is `FILE *`. Any functions you see using an `int fd` is an extension and not standard C. Most commonly that would be [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) extensions.

`int` file descriptors exist because it's what the underlying kernel uses to describe files. On those systems using file descriptors `FILE *` is a wrapper for a file descriptor, adding buffering etc. But not all systems use file descriptors, for example I'm pretty sure Windows doesn't, though I haven't verified that. On those systems, `FILE *` wraps something else more appropriate there.

Comment: For Windows, they are of pointer type mostly because it was practical to implement it as such in C. The only thing pointer about them is their type in C. For all other intents and purposes, they are a descriptor, just like an `int` file descriptor.

Answer (score 12):

> Are int valued fd and FILE * the same?

No. They are not.

File descriptor is an `int` whereas a `FILE *` is a file pointer. The main difference is that the latter is buffered while the former is not.

A file pointer (`FILE*`) typically contains more information about the stream such as current location, end of file marker, errors on the stream etc. But a file descriptor is simply a positve integer representing a "file" (which could a pipe, socket or any other stream).

You can get file descriptor from file pointer using `fileno()`:

```
int fd = fileno(fp);
```

Comment: +1 for showing the conversion from FILE* to int fd, but there should be a precaution not to do that because it is easy to invalidate the buffer after calling read/write/seek on an int fd, breaking functionality which works with FILE*.